# slice indices must be integer, it's already it. how to go beyond this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I tested this functions on an array and a matrix; it's giving the same TypeError about slice indices. double / are used so my indice is really an integer.

```
def getpar(PSI):
    n = PSI.shape[0]
    x = n//2+1
    gamma = PSI[0:x]
    c = PSI[(x + 1):n]
    return gamma,c

getpar(np.matrix([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[2,4,5],[2,5,2]]))
```

it appears that the calculation of x is the problem.

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Azerty\PycharmProjects\toto\venv37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3325, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-20-f29d42dbbc56>", line 1, in <module>
    getpar(np.matrix([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[2,4,5],[2,5,2]]))
  File "C:/Users/Azerty/PycharmProjects/toto/venv37/HARST/HARST.py", line 12, in getpar
    x = itn//2+1
  File "C:\Users\Azerty\PycharmProjects\toto\venv37\lib\site-packages\numpy\matrixlib\defmatrix.py", line 195, in __getitem__
    out = N.ndarray.__getitem__(self, index)
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Comment: `x = int(n//2+1)` - _now_ x is really an integer.

Comment: This line from the error traceback `x = itn//2+1` is not present in the code you showed us.  Please show us the real code.

Comment: The code in your question doesn't match that's shown in the traceback.

Comment: The code as posted works!  Returns 3 rows of the matrix plus a (0,3) shape matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using a float to index the array. numpy floats cannot be converted to an int using `//`. So you can do it this way:

```
x = int(n//2+1)
```

You can also `print(x, type(x))` and you will see what it is.